# Break out of a python multiprocessing manager list

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am implementing a process and I want to stop it when the Manager.list() reaches a certain number, how do I do it?

My code is here, it's not just working, could someone be of help? I don't want to use threads.

```
from multiprocessing import current_process, cpu_count
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import sys

# noinspection PyBroadException
def pool_process(value, _results):
    """
    Spreading work across a pool of Python Processes
    :param value: to be worked on
    :param _results: the array that holds them
    """
    try:
        _results.append(value)
    except:
        print "FATAL: %s running pool_process(%s, %s) exited with %s" % \
              (current_process().name, value, _results, sys.exc_info())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count() * 2)
    pool_mgr = Manager()
    results = pool_mgr.list()

    for each in xrange(0, 1000):
        pool.apply_async(pool_process, [each, results])

    check = True

    while check:
        if len(pool_mgr.list()) == 100:
            check = False
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
            print len(pool_mgr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that I suggest you try out:

```
if len(results) >= 100:
```

and

```
try:
    if len(_results) < 100:
        _results.append(value)
except:
```

The problem is that you are processing in parallel. So these transactions can happen:

```
if len(results) == 100: # 99
_results.append(value)
_results.append(value)
if len(results) == 100: # 101
```

You want to stop not only at 100 but you do not want more values than 100. So you should take the >= sign.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I didn't even see the little mistakes I made, like len(pool_mgr.list()), in place of len(results). And for the tests, it really is the deal.

Comment: I want to know: can this method successfully close opened resource like a network?

Comment: When a process shuts down then all of its opened network ressources are closed and freed. Is this an answer?

Comment: Did you mean to say, THIS IS THE ANSWER, in place of IS THIS AN ANSWER? Please, which do you mean? Thanks.

Comment: "Is this an answer?" = "This is the answer for me. Does this answer help you, do you understand this, does this answer your question." This is what I mean, when I write this. I can happen that I may not undestand the question. So I want to ask "Does this answer make sense to you?"

Comment: OK then, you're right. Thanks for being so helpful. You rock!